# What is the meaning of "drop" and "sgd" while training custom ner model using spacy?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, nltk, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am training a custom ner model to identify organization name in addresses. 
My training loop looks like this:-

```
    for itn in range(100):
        random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
        losses = {}
        batches = minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=compounding(15., 32., 1.001))
        for batch in batches
            texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
            nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer,
                       drop=0.25, losses=losses)

        print('Losses', losses)
```

Can someone explain the parameters "drop", "sgd", "size" and give some ideas to how should I change these values, so that my model performs better.

Answer (score 3):

You can find details and tips in the spaCy documentation:

https://spacy.io/usage/training#tips-batch-size:

> The trick of increasing the batch size is starting to become quite popular ... In training the various spaCy models, we haven’t found much advantage from decaying the learning rate – but starting with a low batch size has definitely helped
>
> `batch_size = compounding(1, max_batch_size, 1.001)`
>
> This will set the batch size to start at 1, and increase each batch until it reaches a maximum size.

https://spacy.io/usage/training#tips-dropout:

> For small datasets, it’s useful to set a high dropout rate at first, and decay it down towards a more reasonable value. This helps avoid the network immediately overfitting, while still encouraging it to learn some of the more interesting things in your data. spaCy comes with a decaying utility function to facilitate this. You might try setting:
>
> `dropout = decaying(0.6, 0.2, 1e-4)`

https://spacy.io/usage/training#annotations:

> `sgd`: An optimizer, i.e. a callable to update the model’s weights. If not set, spaCy will create a new one and save it for further use.

Answer (score 1):

The drop, sgd and size are some of the parameters you can customize to optimize your training.

drop is used to change the value of dropout.

size is used to change the size of the batch

sgd is used to change various hyperparameters such as learning rate, Adam beta1 and beta2 parameters, gradient clipping and L2 regularisation.

I consider the sgd to be a very important argument to experiment with.
To help you, I wrote a short blog post showing how to customize any spaCy parameters from your python interpreter (e.g. jupyter notebook). No command line interface required.